# Excel, Power Query: Pull columns from source workbook based on date

Tags: excel, powerquery

So this is a longshot, as I'm thinking it might be too complicated to explain an answer (if there is one) here. But I'll give it a shot. I track our client membership in a table like so:

Columns A - G, has information like ID number, DOB, Phone, etc... stuff that doesn't change.

Starting with H, each column represents a month (H is January, I is Feb, etc.). For each client, in each month I document if they are in the membership or not. So for example, the source wb looks like this:

| ClientID | January | February |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | Yes | No |
| 100002 | Yes | Yes |

Basically, I want to set up a query in another wb that pulls only the column that I want from the source wb based on today's date. I want my staff to have the mirror spreadsheet on their desktops and when they refresh, they get only the desired column. Since it's a membership, it would have to be the previous month. So when the current calendar month is February, and the staff refreshes, I want the excel to pull columns A - G (A only shown in the example) and also the January column, but not February. Then when March comes along, again pull A - G, and February only (not Jan or any other months). The point being to review if a member has cancelled (like in February in the example) and call the member.

I've been able to setup a query with the full table. But I need it to filter out the undesired columns, and hopefully contingent on the current date.

I get around pretty good on VBA, so I can program something. But I need help with this!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is loaded in PowerQuery, click select columns A-G, then Transform .. Pivot Columns ... Unpivot other columns ...

Filter the results in the Attribute column to select the month you are looking for